# Writing VBA to filter pivot table items in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

If I write VBA to automatically filter a pivot table in Excel, it seems that I have to specify each record to be either visible=True or visible=false.  Isn't there a way to only specify what I want checked?

For example:

```
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("COB_TITLE")

        .PivotItems("CMD GRP").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("G1").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("G2").Visible = True


    End With
```

instead of

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("COB_TITLE")

        .PivotItems("CMD GRP").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("G1").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("G2").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("G3/G5/G3 FIRES/REE/G7/HAST/G9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G8").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("DIV ENG").Visible = False

    End With
```

I was certain I had recorded a macro at one time that had only what I selected.

- Continued..

So I wrote this string `function VisibleList(strSLIDE)` that produces a list like this:

```
.PivotItems("HHBN").Visible = False
.PivotItems("CMD GRP").Visible = False
.PivotItems("G1").Visible = True
.PivotItems("G2").Visible = True
.PivotItems("G3/G5/G3 FIRES/REE/G7/HAST/G9").Visible = True
.PivotItems("DIV ARTY").Visible = False
.PivotItems("G3 FIRES").Visible = False
.PivotItems("G4").Visible = True
```

I was hoping I could embed it like this:

```
strPivotItems = VisibleList("DIV STAFF")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("COB_TITLE")
         strPivotItems
    End With
```

I was assuming I could do this like I embed SQL.  Is there a way to generate this for VBA?

Comment: Everything you need to know about pivot tables and VBA (or pretty close to it). https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

Comment: Found that. OK, now I know I'm on the right track.

Comment: @monty327 did you find a solution for your question ? or do you need assistance ?

Comment: I'm creating a loop that will generate the .PivotItem statements that I need for the entire record set. But I wouldn't mind additional suggestions.

Comment: I added how I have attempted to address this problem.  Each 'slide' will have randomly different Pivot items selected so it means that the entire list needs to be addressed each time.  I created a VisibleList function that produces the entire list (100 items) even though only 1 or 2 items are selected.

Comment: @monty327 have you tried my code in my answer below ? any feedbacks ?

Comment: Yes. I had to put this on hold. Your answer has given me a partial idea to the present solution.  But I wanted to post exactly what I did. I will do that before marking it "answered". Thank you.

Comment: @monty327 that's not correct, you took my answer, and instread of marking my answer as "ANSWER" , you copied the code, added other code line to your code (that were not part of your  post), and then posted it as your answer (not giving the credit to mine) - not entirely fair, right ?

Comment: You are correct because my question does not say what I wanted to do.  You DID give the answer how to filter a Pivot table. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @monty327 thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is what you mean, but give the code below a shot:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivotItems()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld  As PivotField
Dim PvtItm  As PivotItem

' set Pivot Table
Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

' set Pivot Field to "COB_TITLE"
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("COB_TITLE")

' loop through all Pivot Items in "COB_TITLE" Pivot Field
For Each PvtItm In PvtFld.PivotItems

    ' check what is the Pivot item Name
    Select Case PvtItm.Name
        Case "CMD GRP", "G1", "G2"  ' <-- visible Filter Items list
            PvtItm.Visible = True

        Case Else
            PvtItm.Visible = False

    End Select
Next PvtItm

End Sub
```